# My Json created in Gson comes out in a single line when I look at it in the web

Tags: java, mysql, rest, jakarta-ee, gson

I am creating a RESTful web service using java, MySQ, Jersey, and Gson. It works but my only problem is when I run it on the server and go to the localhost site of my project the JSON is all in one line.

This is the output of the JSON on the web.

```
 "[\n{\n\"id\":5,\n\"subject\":\"Math\",\n\"subjectAcronym\":\"MT\",\n\"classNumber\":2550,\n\"className\":\"Linear Algebra\",\n\"unit\": 3,\n\"prerequisite\":true,\n\"corequisite\":false\n}\n]"
```

This is the class in the code.

```
@GET
@Path("/Classes")
@Produces("application/json")
public String feed() {
    String feeds = null;
    try {
        ArrayList<ClassList> feedData = null;
        ClassManager projectManager = new ClassManager();
        feedData = projectManager.GetFeeds();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(feedData));
        feeds = gson.toJson(feedData);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Error"); // Console
    }
    return feeds;
}
```

The `GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()` in the code prints out in the console the way I want it to print out in the web.

The output in the console of eclipse.

```
[     
   {
     "id": 5,
     "subject": "Math",
     "subjectAcronym": "MT",
     "classNumber": 2550,
     "className": "Linear Algebra",
     "unit": 3,
     "prerequisite": true,
     "corequisite": false
  }
]
```

I have 2 more classes similar to this one and all show up the same on the web(in a single line). How can make show on the web like a output in the console? Any response is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "on the web"?  The json you posted contains newlines.  Just view it with something that properly displays the formatting.

Comment: when i run it on the apache server i go to the url: http://localhost:8080/RESTfulProject/REST/WebService/Classes the output is shown in one line.

Comment: It doesn't matter where it comes from, it matters how you look at it.  If you don't like the way it's being formatted by whatever you're using now, use something else.

Comment: The display of the JSON is entirely dependent on the software used to display it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your JSON is a string because you set your GsonBuilder to pretty print, which adds newlines and formatting and such. You want to write the JSON with no formatting so it is JSON and not a string. You can also pretty print if you wish. I believe this will solve your problem:

```
@GET
@Path("/Classes")
@Produces("application/json")
public String feed() {
    String feeds = null;
    try {
        ArrayList<ClassList> feedData = null;
        ClassManager projectManager = new ClassManager();
        feedData = projectManager.GetFeeds();
        Gson gson_pretty = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson_pretty.toJson(feedData));
        feeds = gson.toJson(feedData);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Error"); // Console
    }
    return feeds;
}
```

Note that on Google Chrome, JSON is represented on one line. [Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh?hl=en-US) is an extension to change that. Firefox displays JSON by default like this:

[image: Pretty JSON]

Comment: Glad to be of help! Please mark the answer as accepted, then. It’s the check mark under the vote buttons on this answer.